# How to make this navbar overlaps the banner without ruining the design of the navbar and when scrolled the navbar must follow?

Tags: html, css

```css
/*transfonter*/
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontawesomeregular';
  src: url('.../font/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
      url('.../font/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
  font-family: 'Garamond Premiere Pro';
  src: url('../font/garamond_premier_pro_bold/GaramondPremrPro-Bd.eot');
  src: url('../font/garamond_premier_pro_bold/GaramondPremrPro-Bd.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../font/garamond_premier_pro_bold/GaramondPremrPro-Bd.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../font/garamond_premier_pro_bold/GaramondPremrPro-Bd.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
}

/*general*/
.font-Awesome{font-family: 'fontawesomeregular';}
.font-GaramondPremierePro{font-family: 'Garamond Premiere Pro';}
.font-CormorantGaramond{font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;}
.font-GreatVibes{font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;}
.white{color: #ffffff;}
.magenta{color:#ad1a33;}


/*Header by order*/

  /*navbar*/
  #header .navbar{background-color:black;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); border:none;min-height:82px;border-radius: 0;position: absolute;left:0;position: fixed;z-index: 2;right:0;}
  #header .nav a{color:white; font-family: 'font-GaramondPremierePro';}
  #header .nav {padding: 1% 15%;}
  #header .navbar-header a{font-size:24px;margin-top: 3%;margin-left: 50%;color: white;}
  /*carousel*/
  #header .header-banner{ width:100%; height:663.31px; padding:0px !important; top:0; }
  #header .header-banner-graydiv{background-color: black; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0; right: 0; vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center; horizontal-align: middle; margin: 14% 15% 9% 15%; bottom: 0%; padding: 4%;} 
  #header .header-banner-graydiv h3{font-size: 50px;}
  #header .header-banner-graydiv h1{font-size:92px;}
  #header .header-banner-graydiv h4{font-size: 39px;margin-top: -2%;margin-bottom:4%; display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;}
  #header .header-banner-graydiv h4::before,.carousel-inner .header-banner-graydiv h4::after{ content: "";width: 76px;height: 4px;background: #ffffff;margin: 5px;}
  #header .header-banner-graydiv p{font-size:20px;}
  /*subscribe*/



/*Content by Order*/

/*Footer by Order*/


/*RESPONSIVENESS*/

  /*MOBILE*/

  @media screen and (max-width: 767px)
  {

  }
  /*TABLET*/
  @media screen (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
  {

  }
  /*DESKTOP*/
  @media screen and (min-width: 992px)
  {

  }

  /*Custom*/
  @media screen and (max-width: 1305px)
  {
    #header .nav {margin: auto 0;padding: 0;}
    #header .navbar-header a{margin: auto 0;}
    #header .navbar{padding-top: 15px}
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond|EB+Garamond|Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--header-->
 <div id="header">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand font-GreatVibes" href="#">Your Company Name</a>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
           <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-search" title="fafa"></i></a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
     <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="item active">
      <img src="https://images.alphacoders.com/469/46961.jpg" class="header-banner" >
      <div class="header-banner-graydiv">
        <h3 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">WELCOME TO</h3>
        <h1 class="font-GreatVibes white">Your Restaurant Name</h1>
        <h4 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">FOOD &amp RESTAURANT</h4>
        <p class="font-CormorantGaramond white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="item">
            <img src="https://images4.alphacoders.com/769/76996.jpg" class="header-banner" >
      <div class="header-banner-graydiv">
        <h3 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">WELCOME TO</h3>
        <h1 class="font-GreatVibes white">Your Restaurant Name</h1>
        <h4 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">FOOD &amp RESTAURANT</h4>
        <p class="font-CormorantGaramond white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
      </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
             <img src="https://images.alphacoders.com/469/46961.jpg" class="header-banner" >
       <div class="header-banner-graydiv">
         <h3 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">WELCOME TO</h3>
         <h1 class="font-GreatVibes white">Your Restaurant Name</h1>
         <h4 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">FOOD &amp RESTAURANT</h4>
         <p class="font-CormorantGaramond white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
       </div>
        </div>
    </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
   </div>
 </div>
<!--end of header-->

<!--content-->
<!--end of content-->

<!--footer-->
<!--end of footer-->


 
</body>
</html>
```

The navbar and the banner must be both on top but the navbar must overlap the banner. The navbar must also follow when the user is scrolling. And if you can help me in this: how to make the banner and the gray div inside the banner both responsive as the screen resizes?

My navbar is bootstrapped and it's hard to fix the responsiveness with other elements.

html code:

```
<!--header-->
    <div id="header">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                          </button>
                          <a class="navbar-brand font-GreatVibes" href="#">Your Company Name</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">ABOUT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">SERVICES</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">BLOG</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/">CONTACT</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-search" title="fafa"></i></a></li>
                          </ul>
                    </div>
              </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                  </ol>
                 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="img/head_banner.jpg" class="header-banner" >
                        <div class="header-banner-graydiv">
                             <h3 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">WELCOME TO</h3>
                             <h1 class="font-GreatVibes white">Your Restaurant Name</h1>
                             <h4 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">FOOD &amp RESTAURANT</h4>
                             <p class="font-CormorantGaramond white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/sample_carousel1.jpg" class="header-banner" >
                        <div class="header-banner-graydiv">
                             <h3 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">WELCOME TO</h3>
                             <h1 class="font-GreatVibes white">Your Restaurant Name</h1>
                             <h4 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">FOOD &amp RESTAURANT</h4>
                             <p class="font-CormorantGaramond white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                          <img src="img/sample_carousel2.jpg" class="header-banner" >
                            <div class="header-banner-graydiv">
                                 <h3 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">WELCOME TO</h3>
                                 <h1 class="font-GreatVibes white">Your Restaurant Name</h1>
                                 <h4 class="font-GaramondPremierePro white">FOOD &amp RESTAURANT</h4>
                                 <p class="font-CormorantGaramond white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod <br> tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna. aliqua. Ut enim ad minim </p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                  <!-- Left and right controls -->
                          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
            </div>
    </div>
<!--end of header-->
```

CSS:

```
*general*/
.font-Awesome{font-family: 'fontawesomeregular';}
.font-GaramondPremierePro{font-family: 'Garamond Premiere Pro';}
.font-CormorantGaramond{font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;}
.font-GreatVibes{font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;}
.white{color: #ffffff;}
.magenta{color:#ad1a33;}


/*Header by order*/

  /*navbar*/
  #header .navbar{background-color:black;background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); border:none;min-height:82px;border-radius: 0;}
  #header .nav a{color:white; font-family: 'font-GaramondPremierePro';}
  #header .nav {padding: 1% 15%;}
  #header .navbar-header a{font-size:24px;margin-top: 3%;margin-left: 50%;color: white;}
  /*carousel*/
  #header .header-banner{ width:100%; height:663.31px; padding:0px !important; top:0; }
  #header .header-banner-graydiv{background-color: black; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0; right: 0; vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center; horizontal-align: middle; margin: 14% 15% 5% 15%; bottom: 0%; padding: 4%;} 
  #header .header-banner-graydiv h3{font-size: 50px;}
  #header .header-banner-graydiv h1{font-size:92px;}
  #header .header-banner-graydiv h4{font-size: 39px;margin-top: -2%;margin-bottom:4%; display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;}
  #header .header-banner-graydiv h4::before,.carousel-inner .header-banner-graydiv h4::after{ content: "";width: 76px;height: 4px;background: #ffffff;margin: 5px;}
  #header .header-banner-graydiv p{font-size:20px;}
```

My navbar looks like this:
[image: My navbar looks like this]

But it should look like this:
[image: But it should look like this]

Comment: Would you be able to create a working demo of what you have at the moment? (snippet, jsfiddle, codepen etc) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer without a working example but have you tried:

```
#header .navbar {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index: 1;
}
```

That'll position the navbar above the content and set the background to semi-transparent dark grey / black.

Comment: I added a working code, your code is working i just add position: fixed;z-index: 2;right:0;

Comment: my problem now is the banner on how to make it responsive hahah

Comment: You should be able to use media queries to make this responsive. For example, you could set the navigation to stop being `position: absolute` on smaller screens.

Comment: do you know how can i wrap the letters/words inside the gray div so that the letters/words will resize responsively?

Comment: All I can think of are `overflow-wrap: break-word;` or `word-break: break-all;`. Both seem fairly widely supported and should help.